# Selecting filtered related objects in django

Tags: python, sql, django, orm, django-orm

I've got two models like this (simplified):

```
class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField('content')
    #...

class Vote(models.Model):
    user = ForeignKey(User)
    status = models.TextField(choices = some_choices, default = 'likes')
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    #...
```

What i want to do is to select (using one query) posts using some filter with one particular (let's say current) user's votes on this posts (it's okay if he didn't vote for it), so I can then output all posts and the user can see which ones he liked, which ones he didn't and which ones he didn't vote at all.

`select_related` for `Vote` model will not help here, because related objects cannot be filtered, so I guess I should do something with extra, but I cannot figure out what arguments should I pass.

So I guess, it should be something like:

```
Post.objects.filter(content__contains="test").extra(tables="app_vote", where={'my_vote_status': 'something here perhaps?'})
```

Could you please help me to understand how make a query like this?

**UPD:** schacki provided a good solution, the only problem is that I want to access votes by different users from the template, somtehing like `Post.vote_by_me` and `Post.vote_by_this_user` or `Post.vote_by_top_user`

Comment: how are you relating `Post` and `Vote`? you're leaving something essential out of your example

Comment: oops, you're right. Thank you for pointing that out, I've added relation to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, If you proper want answers, sometimes you should look for them yourself :)

Here's how I've solved my problem:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(content__contains="test"
    ).extra(select={    
                    #extra selects vote status here for current user
                    "my_vote_status":"""SELECT status FROM blog_vote as vt
                                WHERE vt.user_id = %s
                                AND   vt.post_id = blog_posts.id
                             """ % (request.user.pk) #
    }, tables=['blog_vote'])
```

UPD: probably would work without `tables` argument

Answer (score 1):

It's very difficult to understand what you want, but here is another attempt. First, get your posts:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(whatever)
```

Now you want all the votes by a group of users on the posts, correct?

```
votes = Vote.objects.filter(post__in=posts, user__in=users)
```

Now all you have to do is associate the votes to the posts based on, say, the user id:

```
votes_by_user_by_post = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
for v in votes:
    votes_by_user_by_post[post.id][v.user_id].append(v)

for post in posts:
    post.votes_by_user = votes_by_user_by_post[post.id]
```

Performance-wise, it's fine to do this in two queries plus some scripting. They aren't complicated queries and the scripting part is just two for-loops.

Comment: Well, yeah, but I want to do it via extra, so i can actually select votes from 2 or more different users and save them as Post's different variables (typical situation is viewing someone's votes for posts and viewing your own votes on the same posts in the same view)

Comment: It's not the only reason I want to do it this way actually, but that story is a little long :)

Comment: Could you explain in more details, what you want to do rather than assuming that it must be done with extra. This would help all to come up with the best solution. Please describe in your own words what you would like to retrieve.

Comment: yea, gonna need some more info. why couldn't you just do `user__in=`, then iterate through the result, extract the posts, set the variables manually, etc?

Comment: why would I iterate if I can select everything I want using extra? The thing is I am not sure how to do it properly :)

Comment: I cannot do user_in, because I won't get results without votes then

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you will need two objects to pass into context. Try like this, where me and other_user must be valid user objects.

```
posts.vote_by_me=Post.objects.filter(content__contains="test",vote_set__status="something here perhaps?",vote_set__user=me)
posts.vote_by_other_user=Post.objects.filter(content__contains="test",vote_set__status="something here perhaps?",vote_set__user=other_user)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good solution, the only problem is that I want to refer to access this votes in a template. Something like Post.vote_by_me and Post.vote_by_this_user

Comment: And there is another problem - it would not return posts without votes by specified users

Comment: I am sorry, I do not seem to understand your requirements then; if you want a proper answer, provide more details, we cannot guess.